# Wake on Lan password

Tags: passwords, wake-on-lan

I have a Windows 7 machine, with Intel 82567LM LAN Card. I am trying to enable Wake on Lan with password. Can somebody please tell me how to set the password for Wake on Lan.
I shall be grateful for any pointers/links etc. 
Thanks.

PS. Can someone please suggest a small utility for wake on lan, that supports password.

Comment: Does the card allow you to set password? O do you want to set a password to stop people using the utility that send the WoL command?

Comment: I never knew this existed, so for those who didn't know either: it's called "SecureOn" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Security

Answer (score 2):

The only Wake On LAN password that exists is supplied by the motherboard, not the network card.

It is called the SecureON Password.

Check with your motherboard manufacturer or motherboard website.